# Onclick не расчитывает остальные input-ы

Tags: php, javascript

Когда нажимаем на кнопку, должен рассчитать скидку, он у меня рассчитывает только первую, а остальные не рассчитывает. Что сделать?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>#</td>
    <td>Koli4estvo</td>
    <td>Cena</td>
    <td>Skidka</td>
    <td>Stoimost so skidkoi</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <?php print $dost[ 'id']?>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="field1" value="<?php print $dost['koli4estvo']?>">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="field2" value="<?php print $dost['cena']?>">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="field3" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="field4" value="">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <table/>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Calculate</button>
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      $x = (document.getElementById("field2").value * document.getElementById("field3").value) / 100;
      $y = document.getElementById("field2").value - $x;
      document.getElementById("field4").value = document.getElementById("field1").value * $y;
    }
  </script>
```

[image: button onclick]

Comment: ID элементов должны быть уникальными в рамках документа. `document.getElementById("field2")` возвращает 0 или 1 элемент, но никак не 3.

Comment: А ещё должно быть `</table>`, а не `<table/>`.

Comment: @Regent ладно там с table-ми, id элементы уникальные же

Comment: Судя по картинке, в таблице не одна строка с `input`ами. Я предположил, что у `input`ов в других строках такие же ID.

Comment: Чтобы быть максимально корректным, скажу так: в функции `myFunction` значения считаются только для первой строки. Последующих строк в представленном HTML коде нет, равно как и каких-либо действий с ними в представленном JS.

Comment: Переименуйте вопрос, чтобы название отражало суть

Comment: @qwerty `onclick` - это атрибут DOM элемента, он не может что-либо рассчитывать. Но проблема сейчас не в плохо сформулированном заголовке, а в том, что текст вопроса и скриншот не вяжутся с представленным HTML кодом.

Comment: @Regent ) просто убрал там  if ($dosts->num_rows > 0) while ($dost = $dosts->fetch_assoc()) который выводит данные из базы

Comment: @qwerty вот об этом я изначально и догадывался. Что нужно сделать: скопировать в вопрос уже финальный (который виден в браузере) HTML, в котором есть несколько (2-3) строк и нет никакого PHP.

Answer (score 1):

В коде только одна строка, поэтому она и выполняется одна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Потоу что `id` должны быть уникальным.